# Loading Screen only on first visit during a session?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

is there any way to make my loading screen appear only on the first visit during a session?

HTML

```
<div class="splash-wrapper">
  <h1 class="splash-text">ehshots.</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes typing { from { width: 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret { 50% { border-color: #fff; } }

.splash-wrapper{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

h1.splash-text {
    color: #fff;
    font: 300% Montserrat;
    border-right: .1em solid black;
    width: 12.5em;
    width: 6.5ch;
    margin: 2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: typing 1.5s steps(20, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite alternate;
}
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
 jQuery('.splash-wrapper').fadeOut("slow");
},3000);
```

https://codepen.io/marlxnw/pen/LYeJOEm

At the moment the loading screen comes again and again when I go to the start page.

Comment: You can use cookie or session storage

Answer (score 1):

Simpily you can save all users ip in session. When user opens your website check is this ip exist in session or not. If exist, it means it is not his first time in this website. Otherwise write this ip to session

Comment: how do I store the IP of the users? Sorry im new to this topic.

Comment: @marlxnw You just need one meta tag:
`<meta name="ip" content="<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>">`  it is for fetching users ip addres.
Add one line js code for save this ip to session:
`sessionStorage.setItem("userIp", $("meta[name=ip]").attr("content"))`

Comment: I just looked it up, storing IP is forbidden in Germany.

Comment: But you are not storing IP in your DB. Each ip is storing by client browser.